# How do I disable 5GHz channel with ath9k driver module?

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, atheros

I am looking for a way to disable the 5GHz in ath9k other than setting the country code. I have found that there is a patch files for the ath9k or actually the latest kernel 3.19 and 4.0 updated this patch to the ath9k driver.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ath9k_platform.h

I have now upgraded my machine to kernel 4.0 but I don't know how to enable/disable this feature? is there anyone can help!
Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Why do you want to disable 5GHz?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `modinfo ath9k | grep parm`.  Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: since we have a project only need 2.4GHz, and 5GHz will cause the regulation problem. And I can't use the country code to disable the 5GHz, since our kernel is old 3.10.55 which do not take action after country code setting implemented.

Comment: I have checked the modinfo on ath9K which only show couple of int parameter...but not disable or enable 5GHz. below is the patch code for the changes, the topic also mentioned it is allow to disable bands?????                      https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/package/kernel/mac80211/patches/543-ath9k-allow-to-disable-bands-via-platform-data.patch?rev=37766

Comment: there is only the below parameter debug:Debugging mask (uint)nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

Comment: When you say "I am looking for a way to disable the 5GHz in ath9k other than setting the country code" In my case setting another country code would be fine as I'm also looking at disabling 5Ghz but can't find a country code that actually disable 5Ghz. What country code do you have in mind? Thanks

Comment: Hi RockPeach, You could use iw reg set =KZ or You could edit the CRDA files and set REGDOMAIN=KZ. The CRDA files is located in  /etc/default. The code developer Felix provided some support to me, and I am able to hack the code and disable the 5GHz by driver.